# How to perform multiple write from single item/line using Spring-Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

How can I perform multiple write from single item with the given data using spring-batch?

Do I need to read the input x times and create the object then write or read the input once and perform multiple write?

input:

- id, label1, detail1, detail2, detail3

output1:

- id, label1

output2:

- id, detail1
- id, detail2
- id, detail3

Comment: Are output1 and output2 the same destination (same file, etc)?

Comment: no, they'll need to be written into 2 tables. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch provides a `CompositeItemWriter` that takes a list of `ItemWriter`s.  This writer calls each writer, in turn, with each item.  So if I have an item that needs to be written to two different files in different formats, I can use the `CompositeItemWriter` to write each item to each file.  In your case, you'd use multiple `JdbcBatchItemWriter`s.

You can read more about the `CompositeItemWriter` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html

An example of this `ItemWriter` is shown in the Spring Batch samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/compositeItemWriterSampleJob.xml

Comment: Also looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/multilineOrderJob.xml as my model or item looks exactly as Order. In this case, if I had to write the Order and its list of Item into 2 tables does CompositeItemWriter with multiple JdbcBatchItemWriter applicable. How would I be able to loop thru the Item list?

Comment: Looking further at the ItemWriter's I ended up using an ItemWriterAdapter to wrap an existing service to handle an item/object writing.